# Expectation handling in python

Tags: python, exception, exceptionhandler

Below are two function definition

```
def function1():
   try:
      #Code
      #Code

      #code to read file is here

      #code
      return smth
   
   except Exception as e:
      raise Exception ('smth1smth1') from e
   

def function2():
   try:
      #Code
      smth=function1()
      data= {#some json key value pairs}
      data2=request.post(smth123,data)
      #code
      return smth
   
   except Exception as e:
      print('error:%s, error:%s , %(data.key1, data.key2, str(e)))
      raise Exception ('smth2smth2') from e
```

The test case for this is the file is missing here. I am getting the file missing exception as expected but as variable "data" is not assigned I am also getting the variable referenced before assignment error as well.
I don't want to see the exception (error) thrown from the second function i.e function 2 and see the exception from the first i.e. function1 if there is any. How can I achieve this

Comment: You’ll need multiple try/except blocks if you want to handle the first exception and then continue on to the code that raises the second exception.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: What do you want to print when there's no `data`?

Comment: I want to print the error message when there no file found when file is being read

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `except` block needs to not have dependencies on anything that might have failed in the `try` block.  So you either need to not have `data` in the `except`:

```
def function2():
   try:
      #Code
      smth=function1()
      data= {#some json key value pairs}
      data2=request.post(smth123,data)
      #code
      return smth
   except Exception as e:
      print('error:', e)
      raise Exception('smth2smth2') from e
```

or you need multiple `try` blocks:

```
def function2():
   try:
      #Code
      smth=function1()
   except Exception as e:
      print('error:%s, error:%s , %(data.key1, data.key2, str(e)))
      raise Exception('smth2smth2') from e
   try:
      data= {#some json key value pairs}
      data2=request.post(smth123,data)
      #code
      return smth
   except Exception as e:
      print('error:%s, error:%s , %(data.key1, data.key2, str(e)))
      raise Exception('smth2smth2') from e
```

Or you can use different `Exception` classes to have multiple `except` blocks in a single `try`, each matching a specific class of exception (with the assumption being that each might get raised in a different part of the `try`):

```
class Function1Exception(Exception):
    pass

def function1():
    try:
        #code
        return 'smth'
    except Exception as e:
        raise Function1Exception('smth1smth1') from e
   

def function2():
    try:
        #Code
        smth = function1()
        data = {'key': 'value'}
        data2 = request.post(smth, data)
        # code
        return smth
    except Function1Exception as e:
        print('function1 failed:', e)
    except RequestException as e:
        print(f'request failed: {data.key1}, {data.key2}, error: {e}')
        raise Exception('smth2smth2') from e
```

Note that if you weren't doing that except-wrapping in `function1` at all, you would automatically get a more useful exception class like `FileNotFoundError`, the same way `request.post` will raise a `RequestException` on a failure rather than any old `Exception`.  Re-raising a *more* generic exception (i.e. a regular `Exception`) is actually losing information and making it harder to handle the error.